# android communication usb; why always need to replug USB to get responds data?

Tags: android, usb

I created a Android communication to send and receive data to/from USB

```
int iRes2 = conn.bulkTransfer(epOUT, bcdInfo.cbwBuffer.array(), 31, 2000);
iRes2 = conn.bulkTransfer(epOUT, bcdInfo.finalBSTD.array(), 512, 2000);
                bcdInfo.requestData();
iRes2 = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, bcdInfo.cswBuffer, 512, 2000); 
iRes2 = conn.bulkTransfer(epOUT, bcdInfo.cbwBuffer.array(), 31, 2000);
iRes2 = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, bcdInfo.cswBuffer, 512, 2000);
```

I received the right data. The problem is, **I only get the right data** when :

1. I remove another command communication. Let say the above code is
   command A. If I put command B in the upper of command A then I got
   wrong data of command A.
2. I plug USB to Android device everytime I
   want to debug. Means I need to unplug the USB and replug to Android
   device again before every debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to send a default command to USB to tell to USB that communication is done. After that USB will get ready to receive a new command. Below is my default command, I call it as OK command.

```
 public void goOkCommand(UsbDeviceConnection conn, UsbEndpoint epOUT, UsbEndpoint epIN) {

        ByteBuffer goOk = ByteBuffer.allocate(31);
        goOk.putInt(0xVALUE);
        goOk.putInt(0xVALUE);
        goOk.put(index, (byte) 0xVALUE);
        int iRes2 = conn.bulkTransfer(epOUT, goOk.array(), 31, 2000);//1. SEND OK COMMAND

        //2. PREPARE MEMORY FOR RECEIVED DATA
        byte cswBuffer[] = new byte[13];
        Arrays.fill(cswBuffer, (byte) 0);// put ALL 0 first

        iRes2 = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, cswBuffer, 13, 2000);//3. RECEIVED OK MESSAGE
        iRes2 = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, cswBuffer, 13, 2000);
    }
```